# Установка пакетов в python в PyCharm

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

Здравствуйте.

Есть установленный PyСharm и Python 3.6.

Столкнулся с тем что не все библиотеки устанавливаются. Например `pandas`.

При установке через меню управления библиотеками выдаёт ошибку:

> Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Почитал про эту ошибку. Решение установить Visual Studio 2008, у меня стоит 2015 и с ним не работает.

Попробовал скачать уже скомпилированную библиотеку. То же выдаёт при установке через `pip` ошибки.

Но в системе так же установлен пакет Anaconda.  И в нём есть `pandas`.

Как то можно эту библиотеку подтянуть в PyCharm?

Comment: А при чем здесь вообще PyCharm к установке пакетов? Все пакеты в любом случае появятся у вас в IDE после установки, и не важно установите вы их с помощью того же PyCharm или на прямую через pip, что касается pandas и всех его зависимостей, если вы работаете на win то вам нужно пользоваться уже скомпилированными пакетами https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, плюс numpy+mkl для коректной работы SciPy

Comment: "А при чем здесь вообще PyCharm к установке пакетов?" Устанавливаю пакеты в PyCharm. Какие то устанавливаются нормально. Какие то, как например pandas не устанавливаются. Вот решил разобраться в чём проблема. Опыта у меня пока мало в работе с этой средой и python.

Comment: Странно! Если уже есть пакет и идет в комплекте, как вы говорите, то должно работать, хотя может быть разные совместимости.

Answer (score 1):

как Вам правильно указали в комментариях - устанавливать панду нужно не через IDE, а через консоль системы

```
pip install pandas (pip3 install pandas если пользуетесь linux)
```

если хотите использовать анакондовские модули:

1. у анаконды есть своя IDE Spyder, запускайте(или устанавливайте, а
   затем запускайте) через anaconda-navigator
2. Если не устраивает spyder пропишите в PyCharm путь к интерпретатору анаконды [File] -> [Settings] -> [Build, Execution, Deployment] -> [Console] -> [Python Console] - Python Interpreter - выбираем из выпадающего списка

Comment: В spyder у меня работает.

Answer (score 1):

Надо изменить Project Interpreter `(File | Settings...)` на `python.exe` в вашей Anaconda (где вы уже имеете `pandas`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]